# Getting the error: "No such email address for user." when calling Accounts.sendVerificationEmail( userId ) in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am getting an error when I try to send an email verification link to the user. I have used the email feature of Meteor in other projects without any issues. But in the current project, I am getting this error and I have no idea what could be causing it.

> The user.emails[0].address does have an email address.
>   Exception while invoking method 'sendVerificationLink' Error: No such email address for user.
>   at AccountsServer.Accounts.sendVerificationEmail (packages/accounts password/password_server.js:745:11)
>   at [object Object].sendVerificationLink(server/user/users_methods.js:25:23)

I am using **METEOR@1.3-beta.11** and my code is as follows:

```
**Client:**

let user = { email: signupEmail,password: password }

 Accounts.createUser(user, (err) => {
     if(!err) {         
         Meteor.call('sendVerificationLink');
     }
 })

**Server:**

Meteor.startup(function () {
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://postmaster%40sandboxd9...7.mailgun.org:<pwrd>@smtp.mailgun.org:587';
});

...

Meteor.methods({
  sendVerificationLink() {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    if ( userId ) {
      return Accounts.sendVerificationEmail( userId );
    }
  }
});
```

process.env.MAIL_URL and mailgun is set correctly. I have tested it from server using the following server code and the email was delivered correctly.

```
Email.send({
  to: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  from: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  subject: "Example Email",
  text: "This is a test email."
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `signupEmail` contains a valid email address?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error after a day of wasted debugging. There is nothing wrong in the code I posted above in my original question. There was an error in the schema definition for User collection with another package that I had installed - jagi:astronomy. The validation rule for 'Verified' (email verified flag) was set to string. It should have been boolean. I still don't understand why that would prevent from sending out the verification email though. Email field validation itself was correct and email was saved. But once I changed the validation rule to Boolean for 'Verified' field to boolean, the error went away.